# Storage savings of storing an integer as a hexadecimal string

Tags: xml

I have a silly question. When dealing with XML (in which everything is ultimately outputted and stored as a string), would storing an integer as a hexadecimal (base 16) string save more space than a decimal (base 10) string (because it uses less characters, and I imagine the character cost, no matter which charset you might be using, is roughly the same)?

I'd like to think so, but it's a funny question, and I'd like to hear from some other people what they think.

Comment: Please refrain from including tags in your question titles as I am getting tired of removing them..

Comment: I don't think it's significant enough to even bother asking a question about. Does that help?

Comment: You're asking about the space savings of storing a number in hex vs. decimal while using XML? Are you trolling us, good sir?

Comment: If you know it's a silly question, why do you ask it? There's a basic principle in software engineering: don't optimize unless the optimization is necessary to meet your requirements. You've told us nothing about your requirements, but if you really have a requirement to reduce the size of your XML by about 5%, then we can probably suggest much better ways of achieving that.

Comment: M. Babcock -> I was not aware this was an issue. I'll stop now.

Comment: Thanatos-> not trolling you guys. Just dealing with a problem where I need to store a lot of data in a tight space, and do not have a convenient way to do it. Already zipping the XML. ^_^

Comment: Michael Kay -> optimization is necessary here, just trying to see what is possible / manageable. Having another programmer read hex isn't an issue, saving a few bytes here and there over several thousand files is worth the minor effort of adding .ToString("X").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you are correct: base-16 encoding will save some amount of space, at the expense of readability (anyone who can read your new XML could be safely labeled a geek).

But wait, there is more to it! First, why stop at base-16, when you can easily go to base-64 to save even more bytes, at the expense of even more readability? Now even geeks will be out!

Second, many XSD features will become unusable: all these built-in XSD data types, min and max constraints for your numbers, digit patterns, etc. work only with decimal integers.

And third, if you are even minimally concerned about saving space, why bother with XML in the first place? The format treats space rather liberally, intentionally bringing lots of markup to make the data human readable. Which brings us right back where we started: using HEX kills readability.

In short, you are right, but the small savings in space are not worth the trouble.

Comment: Zipped XML: trying to find a happy medium between being able to store data that the computer can quickly process, and a programmer can understand. I think hexadecimal is safe to use here. I was just asking, as it's not something I've ever heard stressed. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Any savings isn't worth the loss in readability.

Additionally, any encodings besides decimal will prevent you from using the standard numeric datatypes (e.g. `xsd:decimal`) in XSD schemas, etc.